# eclipse: "The type Vector is not generic. ..."

Tags: java, eclipse-mars

I have a java project in eclipse and following compile error "The type Vector is not a generic. ...."

[image]

I know this error is comming if there are several compiler level/version settings are wrong.

I have added to the build path the JDK1.8:

[image]

Also in the Compiler settings I have set Version 1.8:

[image]

And last but not least I have also set the correct Java version (1.8) in the Project Facets:

[image]

May be I'm blind but where is the project settings with the wrong Java version ....

Comment: Side question: why `Vector` in 2016? Because Swing?

Comment: Yes, that's of course right. But thats a old project. The code is round about 15 years old ....

Comment: Just for completeness: "Try turning it off and on again" (Here: Do a Project -> Clean, and maybe restart Eclipse after you changed the JRE settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have written in a comment I have "reactivate" a project which is very old ... Not a good idea! Part of the project are also the `cldcapi11.zip` (which is a jar with a ".zip" suffix) and the `midpapi20.jar`. Parts of these both jar's also some JDK classes like `java.util.Vector` and `java.util.Timer` and some more. For compiling the stuff I must remove both jar's or put both jar's behind the JDK8 library ...

ARRRGH! Who collects official JDK classes in his jar file?!? Not nice...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "shade" job to move the non-generic JDK Collection classes to a different package (such as backport.java.util.Vector) and update the references in the cldcapi11/midpapi20 jars. This will give you new cldcapi11-shaded and midpapi20-shaded jars that you can include in your apps.

Agreed on the "ARRRGH!"! It's annoying to have to rebuild others' incorrectly built artifacts.